# Use Javascript to make Image visible when page opens

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for Javascript that will fire when page opens and sets Image1 visibility to true.

Thanks

Comment: If the image needs to be visible when the page opens then why don't you change the CSS and avoid using JavaScript?  Are you trying to punish your users?

Comment: I'm not familiar with css, can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referencing the CSS [`visibility`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp) property:

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById( 'Image1' ).style.visibility = "visible";`

};
```

or the [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) property:

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById( 'Image1' ).style.display = "block";

};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to occur right away utilize the document.onload method. I.e.

```
document.onload = loadFunc;

function loadFunc() {
document.getElementById( 'Image1' ).style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Image1").visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
```